# Facebook can't scrape my page and linter tool says document returns no data

Tags: debugging, facebook-opengraph, scrape

Can anybody tell me why Facebook doesn't scrape my page, and also the debug/linter tools cant scrape it? I've searched and searched and can't find a way to fix it.
As far as I can tell all the og:tags and scripts are implemented correctly.

The page is at http://www.coincident.dk

The debug url is this: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.coincident.dk

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like Facebook *is* scraping your page successfully, just not *fully*. Weird.

I would try moving the OG meta tags lower in the header. After your `content-type` meta tag at the very least.

These problems might be due to character encoding issues. If the Facebook scraper is relying on the `content-type` tag to know the encoding is UTF-8, they it might not be reading your OG tags correctly.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Well I pretty much have tried all of things like that I could come up with.... Tried moving the again and still no change :-/

Comment: Been looking a bit in the server logs and I see this...

69.63.190.246 - - [27/Nov/2011:20:28:20 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 3676 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

?? looks like it's getting a response code: 403

How can that be?

Comment: Hmm, perhaps your Apache/.htaccess config has some funny settings? Sometimes servers are set up to deny access to some user agents, to avoid image hot-linking and such. Check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372551/block-by-useragent-or-empty-referer

Comment: hmmm, dont know what to do, experimented with several things in the .htaccess file, bu t can see what is doing this
Here is my full .htaccess

Comment: Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|\%3D) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^coincident.dk  
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.coincident.dk/$1 [R=permanent,L]
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

Comment: RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|raw))$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

Comment: Well tried to write to my server hosts....
i tried scraping my site on my dev server and there it worked, so must be something in the server config which I am not aware of

Comment: Did you ever figure out what the issue was? it now appears to work correctly.