# Authenticate a web service for mobile applications

Tags: asp.net, wcf, web-services

I have created a sample WCF application which is currently used by Mobile applications currently what the problem is it can be accessed by any one using the soap request who knows the url where its hosted is there any way to restrict this by saying that only the mobiile applications for which this was created should access the web service

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with a useragent restriction that you only allow mobileuseragents.

Use a htcacces to block all other useragents u dont want.

[Block by useragent or empty referer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7372551/block-by-useragent-or-empty-referer)

Comment: How can i implement this in asp.net wcf application