# Ban robots from website

Tags: bots, robots.txt, web-crawler

my website is often down because a spider is accessying to many resources. This is what the hosting told me. They told me to ban these IP address:
46.229.164.98
46.229.164.100
46.229.164.101

But I've no idea about how to do this.

I've googled a bit and I've now added these lines to .htaccess in the root:

```
# allow all except those indicated here
<Files *>
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 46.229.164.98
deny from 46.229.164.100
deny from 46.229.164.101
</Files>
```

Is this 100% correct? What could I do?
Please help me. Really I don't have any idea about what I should do.

Comment: looks like an .htaccess file not a robot.txt ,you should talk to the "hosting" and ask for precisions.

Comment: Yes I did a mistake, now I've removed these lines from robots.txt and write them into .htaccess. They just told me that these spiders where using too much resources and that I should ban their address :/

Comment: So are you having a specific problem with what you posted?

Comment: @PatrickQ no, I had a problem 1 hrs ago, now my hosting shutted down the website and is waiting for me to find a solution...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

based on these

https://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_46.229.164.98 
https://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_46.229.164.100 
https://www.projecthoneypot.org/ip_46.229.164.101

it *looks* like the bot is http://www.semrush.com/bot.html

if thats actually the robot, in their page they say

```
To remove our bot from crawling your site simply insert the following lines to your
"robots.txt" file:

User-agent: SemrushBot
Disallow: /
```

Of course that does not guarantee that the bot will obey the rules. You can block him in several ways. .htaccess is one. Just like you did it.

Also you can do this little trick, deny ANY ip address that has "SemrushBot" in user agent string

```
Options +FollowSymlinks  
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteBase /  
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SemrushBot" bad_user
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^WhateverElseBadUserAgentHere" bad_user
Deny from env=bad_user
```

This way will block other IP's that the bot may use.

see more on blocking by user agent string : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7372572/953684

Should i add, that if your site is down by a spider, *usually* it means you have a bad-written script or a very weak server.

edit:

this line

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "^SemrushBot" bad_user
```

tries to match if User-Agent **begins with** the string `SemrushBot` (the caret `^` means "beginning with"). if you want to search for let's say `SemrushBot` ANYWHERE in the User-Agent string, simply remove the caret so it becomes:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase User-Agent "SemrushBot" bad_user
```

the above means if User-Agent contains the string `SemrushBot` anywhere (yes, no need for `.*`).

Comment: I'm using vBulletin, and now the traffic is 1/3 then the highest traffic I've had in the latest months. When traffic was 100%, website was ok :/

Comment: @daimpa be sure to check your logs. if one spider comes, i can guarantee more will come. its like having your telephone number known to advertising companies. once they spot you, they will call you forever, using different names.

Comment: @Sharky: You start the expression with caret '^'  Does that mean it only matches if the string is at the beginning of the User-Agent?  (And I wonder how long before these uncivilized _____ change their User-Agent.)

Comment: @WGroleau exactly, caret means at the beginning of string. from my experience they don't change their user-agents strings. if someone wants to avoid being blocked, usually changes its user-agent to googlebot or something. anyway keep looking on your logs and build a list of bad user-agents that crawling your sites and block them. BUT be sure to add `Disallow` on robots.txt **whenever applicable** (so they will stop crawling you - because you cannot rely on just blocking from your end, because even blocking it costs resources) and hope for the best... those _______!!!

Answer (score -3):

You are doing the right thing BUT

You have to write that code in **.htaccess** file , not in Robots.txt File.

For denying any Search Engine from crawling your site, the code should like this

```
User-Agent:Google
Disallow:/
```

It will disallow Google from crawling your Site.

I would prefer .htaccess method by the way.